# Dealing with incomplete downloaded file

Tags: android, download, epub

I have collection of ePub files in which new files can be added on user's request.

Now if user wants to download a new ePub file and hence clicks on, say `get latest book`, and book starts downloading to device sdcard.

Now before download gets completed, if user

- presses back button
- he is disconnected from internet
- he terminates the application

then downloaded file remains incomplete.

When next time user opens the app, it tries to open that incomplete file resulting in possible crash of the app.

Any idea on this?

Comment: MD5? Or any other checksum algorithm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671443/how-to-handle-incomplete-image-download-in-android/23009996#23009996

Comment: @GAMA have you working code for this?

Comment: @RaviVaghela Aah, sorry buddy. Almost a decade-old question... Wouldn't be able to trace it. Although, the acceptted answer gives some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the file is fully downloaded before attempting to open it.

You could store the status of the download as complete/incomplete in shared preference, which should be updated when the download is complete. Check this preference before trying to load the file.

Comment: suppose user is trying to open incomplete downloaded file then i'll show error message but what if user wants to complete/restart the download. I'm checking whether a particular file already exists or not before downloading.

Comment: so in case of incomplete download, it'll say file is already downloaded but it'll not be able to open it. how to tackle this?

Comment: You must be downloading in a seperate thread or AsyncTask (best practice). In onPreExecute(), set the sharedPref to indicate incomplete download. onPostExecute(), set the sharedPref to indicate download has been completed. On app start, if this sharedPref is set to download incomplete, you can prompt the user to restart the download.

Comment: that is what i want to do.. but if file already exists, how it can redownload it? will newer(completed download) will overwrite the older one?

Comment: You can always overwrite a file (provided you have the perms) if you choose to. See [this](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/core/files/fileoverwrite.html) for an example of overwriting a file in java.